# ngb modal pass the data to when form edit angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using ngb modal for my form edit. this is my edit button function

```
  editCheckin(data: CheckInModel, details: any) {
console.log(data);
this.modalService.open(details, { ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title', size: 'xl', backdrop: 'static' }).result.then((id) => {
}, (reason) => {

});
```

}
When I click the edit button, above function call and loading popup correctly.
This is my edit button

```
  <button mat-stroked-button type="button" class="action-btn"
                                    (click)="editCheckin(element, details)">
                                    <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>
                                </button>
```

edit object passed correctly. console.log(data) result is like below

[image]

now i need to that console logged data to my pop up. how i pass it.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the component instance directly doing something like

in your modal you add a property :

```
data: CheckInModel
```

and when you call the modal you just do :

```
openModal() {
   const modalRef = this.modalService.open(ModalContentComponent);
   modalRef.componentInstance.data = this.data;
}
```

In my app, I have a custom service that wrap the ngb modal service :

```
export class ModalService {
  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}

  open<C, T>(content: unknown, config?: T, options?: NgbModalOptions): ModalRef<C> {
    const modal = this.modalService.open(content, {
      centered: true,
      backdrop: true,
      size: 'm',
      ...options,
    });
    Object.assign(modal.componentInstance, config);
    return modal;
  }
}
```

This way I can simply call my modal with my service and pass the data :

```
    const ref = this.modalService.open<GenericModalComponent, GenericModalData>(
      GenericModalComponent,
      {
        data: 'this will be passed to the modal instance'
      }
    );
```

The important thing is that the modal have a defined property with the same name (here would be data)

more [Here](https://medium.com/@izzatnadiri/how-to-pass-data-to-and-receive-from-ng-bootstrap-modals-916f2ad5d66e)